# Why do people use peat pots?

Tags: containers, transplanting, peat

Recently I've discovered something called peat pots. Why should I use them? Why wouldn't I just put the plant directly into the ground? Is there any advantage?

Comment: I find that the soil dries out faster, so any neglect proves harmful to the plant.

Comment: Years ago when I used peat pots , I found it was beneficial to rip open the pots when setting them in the garden.

Answer (score 8):

In many cases, it is simply for convenience. However; there are some plants which do not tolerate transplanting. Therefore, to start seeds indoors to get a head start and/ or maximize their strong stocks, people use peat pots so they can transfer them outdoors without transplantation.

One noted example of an intolerant plant is corn.

Comment: ok but if i put that plant with the peat pot to the ground then how it will "use the ground" (take water and nutricients) - it's in a pot after all?

Comment: The peat is just another growing medium which has been pressed and dried. It eventual rots into the soil. It's important to bury the whole peat pot to assure it doesn't turn into a dried out plug. The roots will grow right through the pot as if it's soil.

Comment: In fact you get get your own press and make pots out of suitable materials, such as shredded newspaper, grass clippings, etc.

Comment: Might you consider adding your comments, especially the first one, into your answer? They look like helpful information for future visitors who might not read the comments. It's up to you, though! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

They're used for starting seeds, and not for putting plants into.  Then once the seed has sprouted and grown a bit, you can then transplant the whole thing into soil without disturbing the new roots.  There is also no competition from other seeds that you would get if you put the seeds directly into the ground.

The new roots will also grow right through the peat pot if the bottom is kept moist.  If too dry, it can cause the new plant to be root bound. So, some people recommend keeping them inside a polystyrene cup.

Comment: 1. "keeping them inside a polystyrene cup" why? 2. but don't you water those "starting seeds"? - if watered then peat will tear apart, won't it?

Comment: They don't tear apart easily and don't rot in the time you're using them. The roots have to grow through them, and for that they need to be moist hence the need to sit them with a wet bottom.  Also, if you water from the bottom, the potting mix will wick the water up as needed so that you don't over water the seedling by using sub irrigation.

Answer (score 1):

Peat pots make quick work of starting seeds. The beauty of using peat pots is that transplanting the seeds into the garden becomes a snap. The pot breaks down and becomes part of the soil. There is no packaging to throw away and no plastic to recycle.